# Multiple Actions in a JButton

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, timer, jbutton

In this program, we are supposed to click a button that says "Start" and then the animation will start running across the screen. After we click "Start," the button then changes to a "Pause" button where if you click it, it stops the animation and a "Resume" button appears. I am not sure how to get all three of those actions into one button. Here is the code I have so far:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Start");
      button.addActionListener(new
         ActionListener()
         {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               Timer t = new Timer(100, new
                     ActionListener()
                     {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                        {
                           shape.translate(x, y);
                           label.repaint();
                        }
                     });
               t.start();
            }
         });
```

I know this isn't right. When I run the program, the animation is idle until I hit "Start" which is correct, but then every time I hit the button again, the animation speeds up which is not correct. How do I go about adding different actions to the button?

For instance after the animation is running, I want the "Pause" button to stop the Timer when it is clicked, then to resume the Timer when I hit "Resume." The code I have now creates a new Timer object every time I click it, but this seems to be the only way I get it to work. If I put anything outside the ActionListener, I get a scope error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this isn't right. When I run the program, the animation is idle until I hit "Start" which is correct, but then every time I hit the button again, the animation speeds up which is not correct.

This is because you're creating multiple new `Timer`s each time you press the button.  You should have a single reference to the `Timer` and be making decisions about what to do based on it's current state

```
//...
private Timer timer;
//...

JButton button = new JButton("Start");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    shape.translate(x, y);
                    label.repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
            button.setText("Pause");
        } else if (timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.stop();
            button.setText("Resume");
        } else {
            timer.start();
            button.setText("Pause");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it. I knew the way I had it was creating a new Timer each time which isn't what I wanted. I never thought to put the timer in my private instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

> but then every time I hit the button again, the animation speeds up which is not correct.

Don't keep creating a `Timer` in the `ActionListener`. Every time you click the button you start a new Timer.

Instead create the `Timer` in the constructor of your class. Then in the `ActionListener` you just `start()` the existing `Timer`.

Then the `Pause` and 'Resume`buttons will also just invoke the`stop()`and`restart()` methods on the existing Timer as well.

Comment: This is a problem. I tried doing that but I am getting a "Cannot refer to the non-local variable t defined in an enclosing scope" The only way I can get this to work is to put the constructor for the Timer in the 'ActionListener'.

Comment: @GenericUser01 There's not really enough context to you example code to be able to provide a full solution to that problem, except to say, try making the `Timer` a instance field of the class

Comment: The way to do it is to restructure the code so that the Timer is defined as an instance variable in your class.